# Google Cloud Composer get default service account private key

Tags: airflow, service-accounts, google-cloud-composer

I'm using pymongo (from airflow hook) to connect to a mongo instance which implements FLE (Field Level Encryption) using google kms for the keys. We have a VM which has a service account file and this is how we configured it

```
hook = MongoHook(self.source_conn_id)
creds = json.load(open(self.gcs_service_account_keypath))
kms_providers = {
  "gcp": {
  "email": creds['client_email'],
  "privateKey": creds['private_key'].replace(
    '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n', '').replace(
    '\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n', '')
  }
            }
  auto_encryption_opts = AutoEncryptionOpts(
  kms_providers, key_vault_namespace=self.mongo_key_vault_namespace, bypass_auto_encryption=True)
  hook.extras = {'auto_encryption_opts': auto_encryption_opts }
```

Now I'm trying to do the same in Cloud Composer but I can't find how to access the private key from the default service account in cloud composer. I could export the service account key, add it to secret manager and access it like that but it doesn't seem very good idea.
Any ideas how I can access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three types of service account private keys. Google managed, user managed and user supplied (imported).

You cannot directly access the private key from a compute service as the metadata server does not provide access to private keys - only tokens created from private keys.

The standard recommendation is to use the IAM APIs to sign blobs/JWTs.

Your other option is to use user managed where you download the service account JSON key file and provide that file to your application or load as a secret from Secret Manager or a similar service.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up exporting the key and inserting it into secret manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a service account key following these [steps](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating). Instead of using secret manager, you can put the private key in the GCS bucket associated to your environment and put it in your `data` folder: `gs://bucket-name/data` to make it accessible. For more information of utilization of Cloud storage bucket associated to your Cloud composer environment, you can refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage#folders_in_the_bucket).

Comment: I don't think storing the raw key in a bucket is very wise. I ended up storing it to secret manager